# Print from a for loop into a new data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to print new columns in a new data frame using a for loop. I have built the for loops and have gotten them to print what I want in the console, but am having a hell of a time getting those results into a new data frame. I have tried making a blank matrix with the correct number of rows with the goal of converting the matrix into a data frame after performing the for loop, but I haven't gotten it to work - I can't figure out the correct code inside the for loop to get the results into the matrix. I'm not including the failed code here, I think I need to start a new. Here is my code

```
a <- 2019
z <- 2023

#print each year 12 times
  for(i in a:z){
    print(i);print(i);print(i);print(i);print(i);print(i);
    print(i);print(i);print(i);print(i);print(i);print(i)
  }

#print the sequence 1:12 the number of times that there are years
for(i in a:z) {
  for(i in 1:12) {
    print(i)}}
```

My goal here is one column with each year printed 12 times, and a second column with each month, as shown here with one year:

```
example <- data.frame(yr=c(2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019),m=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid`

```
data <- expand.grid(yr = 2019:2023, m = 1:12)

#     yr  m
#1  2019  1
#2  2020  1
#3  2021  1
#4  2022  1
#5  2023  1
#6  2019  2
#7  2020  2
#8  2021  2
#9  2022  2
#10 2023  2
#....
```

`tidyr` also has some options :

```
tidyr::expand_grid(yr = 2019:2023, m = 1:12)
```

and

```
tidyr::crossing(yr = 2019:2023, m = 1:12)
```

---

Growing dataframe in a loop is highly inefficient hence, using `for` loop is not recommended but if we want to do this for learning purposes, we can do :

```
x <- 2019:2023
y <- 1:12
df <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = length(x) * length(y), ncol = 2, 
                 dimnames = list(NULL, c('yr', 'm'))))
count <- 1
for(i in x){
   for(j in y) {
     df[count, ] <- c(i, j)
     count <- count + 1
   }
}
```

Comment: Aha ok this works great! Do you by any chance know how to print the data using the for loops? I understand it's sometimes ill advised to create a data frame from a for loop, but I would love to know how. I've looked it up in a lot of places and none of the code ever work.

Comment: @sebzee Using `for` loop would be very slow and it is not really recommended. I have updated the answer though if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(yr = 2019:2023, m = 1:12)
```